# algorithm for reducing to the fundamental domain $\mathbb{H}/SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: number-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

I have $y << 1$ and $x \in [0,1]$ uniformly chosen at random and I want to find its representative in the [fundamental domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain#Fundamental_domain_for_the_modular_group) with $\big|\mathrm{Re} \; \tau \big|< \frac{1}{2}$ and $|\tau| > 1$.

[image]

How do we find this representative? And how it related to the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

This question has been considered by Gauss and Legendre, and has been studied quite recently. The magic words are "lattice reduction in two dimensions", and a magic reference is t[his paper of Vallee/Vera](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3jm1cmzinkep05g/ValleeVeraGauss.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an expression for the Möbius transformations that preserve this?

It appears that finding $m\colon\mathbb{H}\rightarrow\mathbb{H}$ such that

$0\mapsto 0$

$\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\mapsto \frac{3+2i}{6}$

$\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\mapsto \frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$

may help.

(I am estimating with 3+2i/6)